# getting the value of textbox of Grid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Now , I am using ASP.net with C# . I have a Grid and there are two text box controls in it. How should I do to get the value of these two text box controls  from JavaScript.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of text box in grid view through java script as follows:

Just add a call to a javascript function on onblur or on keypress or any other event you want, of the textbox control you want to get the value of, like following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" OnBlur = "javascript:return DefaultValue(this);"
     runat="server" Text='1'>
     </asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now in script tag creat a function like this:

```
function DefaultValue(name) {
            var value = document.getElementById(Name.id).value;
            alert(value);
}
```

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

this example will get the control that has an id of "theIDOfMyTextBox" and then place the text into the variable text

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox = document.getElementById("theIDOfMyTextBox");
    var text = textBox.value;
</script>
```

[WC3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script) has an online javascript editor that you can use, as does [google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/)

Comment: Thanks you so much Muad'Dib , but my text box control is in Gird View , can I use like this?

Comment: @lelewin for this to work, all you need is the ID of your textbox.